# spring boot and mybatis auto increase id

Tags: spring, mybatis

I use spring boot and mybatis to insert record to h2 databse,also,use auto increasing id.
first,I and library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then a domain class:

```
@Repository
package com.example.demo.domain;
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
// getter setter and 3 constructor...
}
```

Then a mapper:

```
package com.example.demo.mapper;

import ...;
import com.example.demo.domain.Customer;
@Service
public interface CustomerMapper {
    @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
    @Insert("insert into Customer (name) values (#{name})")
    public int insert(Customer c);
    
    @Select("select * from Customer")
    public List<Customer> sel();
    
}
```

There is also a schema.sql file at root of classpath with contains a sql:

```
drop table if exists customer
create table customer (id int,name varchar)
```

Then a spring boot class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.domain.Customer;
import com.example.demo.mapper.CustomerMapper;

@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.example.demo.mapper")
public class Demo2Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    CustomerMapper customerMapper;
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        customerMapper.insert(new Customer("john"));
        customerMapper.insert(new Customer("james"));
        List<Customer> cus = customerMapper.sel();
        System.out.println(cus.get(0).getId());
        System.out.println(cus.get(1).getId());
    }

}
```

The console prints:

```
0
0
```

It means I insert two person,but their ids are both zero,it is not auto increasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change schema.sql in follow way:

```
drop table if exists customer;
create table customer
(
    id   int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar
);
```

That solution should work.

P.S.
And domain model shouldn't be managed by spring container in follow code:

```
@Repository
package com.example.demo.domain;
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
// getter setter and 3 constructor...
}
```

just delete @Repository annotation

Comment: Hi, @saver. Because quality StackOverflow questions and answers tend to be viewed a great deal, it's best to include an explanation--a code fix is a benefit, but less useful overall than the explanation. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your schema as follows:

CREATE TABLE customer (
id int  AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255)
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);